# VB .NET - App.config - Connection Strings

Tags: vb.net, app-config, adodb

In VB .NET 2019, I have some code to connect to an Oracle database:

```
Private Const connectionString = "Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle.1;Persist Security Info=False;Data Source=someSource;User ID=someUser;Password=somePassword"

Public Function Connect() As Object
    Connect = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Connect.ConnectionString = connectionString 
    Connect.CursorLocation = 3
    Connect.Open
    ...
End Function
```

This code works fine. Now I'm trying to move the connectionString definition to the app.config file.

app.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="TestConnection" connectionString="Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle.1;Persist Security Info=False;Data Source=someSource;User ID=someUser;Password=somePassword" />
</connectionStrings>
```

In my code, I just changed this:

```
Connect.ConnectionString = connectionString
```

By:

```
Connect.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("TestConnection").ConnectionString
```

When I run the code, I get the follow error:
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
System.Configuration.ConnectionStringSettingsCollection.this[string].get returned Nothing.

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong

Comment: if it's VB.NET then why is there a `CreateObject` line? And if it's accessing Oracle then why ADODB ? Is this something copied from an Excel VBA or similar?

Comment: The code was migrated from a vbscript

Comment: ok then can you rewrite using VB.NET? Also check if your output folder (where the exe is located) contains the app.config file and it has the correct `connectionStrings` node

Comment: Yes, I can rewrite but that won't solve my current problem of not being able to retrieve the connection string from the config file. The output is a dll file (Connections.dll) and I do have a Connections.dll.config file in the output directory. Is that correct?

Comment: if your project name is `Connections` then it should be `Connections.exe.config` and that file should contain the connection string.

Comment: Yeah, it's there with the connection string

Comment: What is your project type? Do you have the data access in a class library separate from the main application? The config file needs to be in the main executable project, not a class library.

Comment: Yes, the data access is in a class library and the config file was in the class library. So I moved the connection string to the main executable config file and it works except that it doesn't help me. I'm writing a dll file that will be used by an external application. How can I handle this situation then? I guess it's not possible unless I use an external file

Comment: Pass the connection string into the constructor of the objects in your DLL

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you've done wrong but I just tested the scenario you describe and it worked fine for me. In situations like this, you should always create a test project that isolates the specific functionality you're having trouble with to test it specifically. Here's what I did:

1. Create a new WinForms project.
2. Create a new Class Library project.
3. Reference System.Configuration.dll in both projects.
4. Reference the Class Library project in the WinForms project.
5. Add an appropriate connection string to the App.config file in the WinForms project.
6. Add a class that reads that connection string in the Class Library project.
7. Create an instance of the library class in the WinForms project and get the connection string that it read.

Here's my App.config file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
      <add name="TestConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=True"/>
    </connectionStrings>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.8"/>
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

Here's my library class:

```vb
Imports System.Configuration

Public Class Class1

    Public Property ConnectionString As String

    Public Sub New()
        ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("TestConnection").ConnectionString
    End Sub

End Class
```

Here's my form class:

```vb
Imports System.Configuration
Imports ClassLibrary1

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim testConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("TestConnection").ConnectionString

        Debug.WriteLine(testConnectionString)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim obj As New Class1

        Debug.WriteLine(obj.ConnectionString)
    End Sub
End Class
```

When I run that WinForms project and click the `Buttons`, I see the correct connection string displayed in the Output window both times. If you can do the same and get the same results then you know that what should work, does work. You then need to look for differences between this test scenario and your existing project.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes, it does work this way but my problem is this. How to make it work without this step: Add an appropriate connection string to the App.config file in the WinForms project. Maybe I'm not going the right way with what I want to achieve but my plan was to create a DLL file out of the class library so that different scripts (from different projects) can use this DLL to make connections. By doing this, I wanted to achieve 2 things: avoid the redundant code and especially hide the connection strings from users

Comment: @Mu21, that's not possible. I must have misunderstood what you were trying to do because I assumed that you were trying to do the right thing. When a DLL reads data from a config file using that default mechanism, it reads it from the config file of the application that is referencing it. That's how it works. There are all sorts of third-party libraries that require you to add info to your application's config file for that reason. DLL projects only output things like connection strings to config files so that you can copy them to an application config file.

Comment: @Mu21, *"my plan was to create a DLL file out of the class library"*. The DLL file IS the class library. A Class Library project generates a class library when built, just as a Windows Forms Application project outputs a WinForms application when built.

Comment: @Mu21, *"different scripts (from different projects) can use this DLL to make connections"*. There are no scripts. VB.NET is not a scripting language. You can reference your DLL in any other library or application project you want. Any config data required by the library must be added to the config file of each application. That's how it works because that's how it's supposed to work. How could hiding the connection strings be a good idea when anyone using your library with an application on a different machine would need to edit the connection string to make it work?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanations. 1) The connection strings do not need to be edited unless username/password change and 2) I was reading about the possibility of encrypting the config file, which is the reason why I was trying to do it that way.

Comment: Right now, I have a library file with the connection strings in clear and the different scripts refer to this file. If I encrypt the connection strings (which I did) and put the encryption/decryption functions within the scripts (which I also did), a simple MsgBox will display the password so it serves no purpose so I was trying to "externalize" this part of the script by creating a library file which could be referenced in the existing scripts. Yes, we could always get the source code from the file but at least I could tell the security guys that passwords were not stored in clear.

Comment: You could provide the encrypted config section or entry for the application developers to paste into their config files. Basically, the config system works the way it works so, if you don't like the way it works, don't use it.

Comment: Yes, but there are no config files with vbscript!!! When I said that scripts would be using the class library, that's what I was talking about. It's not a matter of liking it or not, it's a matter of discovering the way things work. I'm not a developer, I'm just trying different things. In any case, I thank you for all the explanations you provided.

Comment: There is nothing in your question about VBScript. You're supposed to provide all the relevant information in your question.

Comment: I did say it, "my plan was to create a DLL file out of the class library so that different scripts (from different projects) can use this DLL to make connections". You just decided to make your own interpretation of what "script" means

Comment: @Mu21, that was in a comment on an answer and, even then, it doesn't mention VBScript. Many beginners refer to VB.NET code as "script" so it seemed likely that you were too because, if you weren't, you should have actually explained that in the question. I'm done here.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Thank you so much for your contribution, I was looking for something like that.